# Typescript - How to solve - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble declaring a variable correctly.

I am using the code here:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(numberOfTab => {
if (numberOfTab) {
this.tabs[numberOfTab].active = true;
} else {...}
```

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'landingPage: { id: 'landingPage', heading: 'shop.landingPage', active: false, loaded: true }'.**

**No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type.**

I don't quite understand why and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface for tabs and define the tabs as a dynamic property name and assign that property to the tabs variable

```js
interface Tabs {
  [key: string]: {
    id: string;
    heading: string;
    active: boolean;
    loaded: boolean;
  };
}

tabs: Tabs = {
  landingPage: {
    id: 'landingPage',
    heading: 'shop.landingPage',
    active: false,
    loaded: true,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To my simple knowledge, Typescript does not know the outcome of activatedRoute.fragment. This makes numberOfTab of type any. You then want to grab the object in tabs[numberOfTab] which basically translates to "tabs[anything]". The outcome can be anything to Typescript. And then you want to set the "active" property on that anything.

Typescript is just warning you: I don't know what tabs[numberOfTab] is.

You can solve this by explicitly stating the type of everything. For example (numberOfTab: number). Of just continue with the any type like (this.tabs[numberOfTab] as any).active = true

Comment: I tried to continue with any type like ```(this.tabs[number Of Tab] as any).active = true``` 
but still the same error occurs

Comment: (numberOfTab: any) after subscribe